# Is it better to import photoshop files or illustrator files into flash?

Tags: 2d, graphics, iphone, flash

I was wondering what would be better to import into flash for when I animate. 
My intention is to animate my characters and objects and then export as a png sequence and make a sprite sheet then take into cocos2d.

Illustrator like flash is vector based but I will have to turn it into pixels anyway to play on a screen.

So I was just wondering what would be better or easier or does it not matter either way?

Additional information: 
I have all the adobe software above at CS5.
I am slightly more comfortable working in Illustrator.
My intention was to make the graphics in illustrator so that I could easily resize my graphics for multiple devices, sometimes I may have to rasterize my illustrator file and add final touches in photoshop.

As I'm sure you can tell i'm pretty new to flash and iphone development so any help or advice would be greatly appreciated, sorry for all the questions.

Comment: possibly migrate this to http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are comfortable with illustrator then i would recommend attempting to use the drawing tools within flash - they are less refined but if you get used to them it will become easier to then animate in flash

Flash is also vector based and you should be able to copy and paste paths/shapes etc.. from illustrator and back to flash

If you need to do any Photoshop tweaks to the animation I would say it would be easier to export the animation as pngs from flash then edit the pngs - if it's the same process per frame then make an action to make your life easier

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter all that much. Since you're feeling more comfortable using Illustrator, I'd chose Illustrator over Photoshop.

If you use Illustrator, you're pretty much resolution independent (unless you use pixel-graphics within Illustrator). This has the benefit, that you can scale/deform your artwork without quality-loss up to the moment where you export it into a sprite-sheet.

I think you should chose the tools based on two factors:

- Will this tool allow me to create the art-style I'm aiming for (eg. using Illustrator for retro-style pixel-art would be a bad choice)
- Do I know the tool well, can I be productive enough using it. It doesn't make sense to use a tool that hinders your productivity too much (unless you absolutely want to learn to use it for future projects)